# Word meaning "interchangeable with other parts."

Tags: single-word-requests

**Need**

I'm looking for a phrase or word that basically means interchangeable with other parts.

**Background**

I'm working on a proposal in which I'm describing a technical solution that consists of several parts which can be connected to other technical solutions (kind of like a connector set).  I think there's a good word for this, but I can't seem to remember what that word is.  I almost feel like it's on the tip of my tongue, but I just can't come up with a single word (or concise phrase might do).  Thanks.

Comment: Could you supply a sample sentence (probably as part of the "Need" section) please?

Comment: *Modules* maybe? Really hard to tell. Give us the sentence, and ideally the whole paragraph. Failing that, the best word for "interchangeable" is, well, *interchangeable*. Whether it's parts or cats or planets, that's the word alright.

Comment: You're not thinking of compatible?

Comment: @Zebrafish Or maybe "plug-compatible"

Comment: Thank you @RegDwight!  I think Modular works!  Thank you to everyone else!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go with *modular*. For instance, for a modular smart phone the user himself can choose to install modules like cameras, ports, and such.

*modular* (from [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/modular), 2019):

> Consisting of separate modules; especially where each module performs or fulfills some specified function and could be replaced by a similar module for the same function, independently of the other modules.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for!  Thank you!